# New requests for /cache/ URLs

Tags: cache, 404, hacking

A few weeks ago requests following this type of pattern:

```
http://mysite/cache/7a226e8aa3a4380444a329a7b0dd0f40  
http://mysite/otherfolder/cache/7a226e8aa3a4380444a329a7b0dd0f40
```

started to appear in my logs. Almost all the requests come from Indian IPs. Anybody know what is generating these requests and the intent?

Comment: I have the same issue, so just checking. Do you have google analytics installed?

Comment: A similar discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017609/undefined-randomly-appended-in-1-of-requested-urls-on-my-website-since-12-jun

Comment: @DmitryDzygin - yes I have analytics installed. Yes, it's similar to the .../undefined post you linked (which I also get) but sufficiently different that I don't believe that the two are related.

Comment: cache/7a226e8aa3a4380444a329a7b0dd0f40 I am having the same hash requests, coming only from chrome though

Comment: Maybe it's an extension? Seriously, the developers of such extensions should be shot on location.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. As I suspected, it was an error caused by an extension.

Anyway, here's an article describing the issue.

http://wizzley.com/url-adding-undefined-on-chrome/

Add the following code to your JavaScript, and everything will be fine.

```
window.suggestmeyes_loaded = true;
```

Don't ask why it's needed, but it works. No more `/cache/` issues from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a script in search of exploit, Google for all exploits related to your CMS with word cache published within the last month.

See also http://www.exploit-db.com/webapps/.